# Is there a quick way to conditionally add a loop to a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a simple way to add an additional loop to a for loop if a condition is met?

In a leaning algorithm that is epsilon-greedy the algorithm is supposed to return the calculated answer with a probability of 1 - epsilon (in this case the calculated answer is an N*N numpy array where some Actn1 > Actn2). However to explore the environment at times the algorithm will generate a random answer.  This means that for a fixed number of episodes, the loop will terminate and return a random answer rather than the calculated answer with probability Epsilon.

```
    for i in range(Episodes)
        ..... 
        if np.random.uniform(0,1) >= ep:
            Ans = StActn1 >= StActn2
        else:
            Ans = np.array(np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(10, 10)))
    return(Ans)
```

Is there a way to force it to go an additional loop if this is the case?  I think I am looking for a simple for loop way to get behavior similar to something like this.

```
  while i <= Episodes or c == 1:
        .....
        if np.random.uniform(0,1) >= ep:
            Ans = QH >= QS
            c=0  
        else:
            Ans = np.array(np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(PlrDm, DlrDm)))
            c=1 
  return(Ans)
```

Can this be done in python?

Comment: Thx! still learning didn't mean to spam, just looking for pointers on the actual implementation of epsilon greedy in python.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only want that extra loop to happen once at most, so you could add a flag:

```
    once_more = False
    for i in range(Episodes)
        ... 
        if np.random.uniform(0,1) >= ep:
            Ans = StActn1 >= StActn2
            once_more = False
        else:
            Ans = np.array(np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(10, 10)))
            once_more = True
    if once_more:
        ...
        Ans = StActn1 >= StActn2
    return Ans
```

Comment: Thanks! 2 quick follow up questions. 1) Is there a way to do it without copying the code base all over again?  I can't call the function again the way it is because Ans, StActn1, StActn2 would be recalculated from scratch unless the function parameters were modified in a cumbersome way.  2) If loops completed are still < Episodes and once_more =True, won't this method cause the program to terminate prematurely?

Comment: 1) You could extract the duplicated code to another function 2) No, it won't. There is no `break` or `return` inside the loop body, so it will not stop early.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the optimal way to go about it but I should've just added an additional condition to the if statement.

```
for i in range(Episodes)
    ..... 
    if np.random.uniform(0,1) >= ep or i == Episodes:
        Ans = StActn1 >= StActn2
    else:
        Ans = np.array(np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(10, 10)))
return(Ans)
```

Comment: It should be `i == Episodes - 1`, otherwise that condition will never be true!